# Two column values in same table Laravel 5.4 merge into Array

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to merge example_1 and example_2 values into array.

example_1 and example_2 are of type int.

```
User::select('example_1','example_2')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
// The result: [{"example_1":"1","example_2":"2"}]
```

example_1 and example_2 if has value 1 and 2 respectively.

I want to have an array : [1,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Eloquent queries return `Collection` objects. Those can be modified easier (through [collections methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods)).

You can use [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-first) to get the first object out of this collection.

Now you can access the variables of the Eloquent User model by calling them like you'd call public class properties.

---

Your final code would look like:

```
$user = User::select('example_1','example_2')
          ->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get()->first();

$array = [ $user->example_1, $user->example_2 ]; 
// The result: [1,2]
```

Comment: this is what I get : [{"a":"5","b":"4"}] I need only [5,4]

Comment: Oh, you are right. Give me a minute @MurlidharFichadia

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Updated it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of this

```
$result = array_only(auth()->user()->toArray(), ['example_1','example_2']);

// Or

$result = User::where('id', auth()->id())->first(['example_1','example_2'])->toArray();

// Finally

$data = array_values($result);
```